# Propagate copts to all dependencies in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a C++ Bazel project where each target should receive different compiler flags (via `copts`) depending on their parent target. For example, consider the dependency graph:

[image]

I would like the different `copts` defined in `target 1` and `target 2` to propagate down to each of the `dependency` targets independently. In other words, I want each `dependency` target to receive the `copts` defined in their parent target(s). This means that there will be two different compiled binaries produced by compiling each of the `dependency` targets, depending on which parent target is depending on it.

Is this possible with Bazel? If not, are there alternative ways of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to explicitly duplicate all of the dependency targets. You could avoid unnecessary duplication in your `BUILD` files with a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html). Then when you want to build or depend on one of those, you just pick which version to use because they'd have different names.

More complicated approaches give you different ways to pick which version of `Dependency A` to use. If the `dependency` targets are binaries (for example), then I don't see any advantage in more complicated approaches.

If they're libraries in the middle of your overall dependency graph, then a [user-defined build setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#user-defined-build-settings) might make sense instead. That duplicates all the intermediate targets automatically, without you needing to modify all the other rule definitions to use a macro that duplicates them. You could then [use select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#build-settings-and-select) to between `Target 1` and `Target 2`, and use the matching `copts`.

Getting even more complicated, you could use [aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) or fully [custom C++ rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/integrating-with-rules-cc.html), but I don't see any reason to do either of those.