# Propagating copts/defines to all of a target's dependencies

Tags: bazel

I have a project that involves multiple BUILD files in a single WORKSPACE, within a fairly complex build system. My goal in short: for some specific target, I want all of its recursive dependencies to be built with an extra set of attributes (`copts`/`defines`) compared to when those dependency targets are built in any other way. I have not yet found a way to do this cleanly.

For example, target G is normally built with `copts = []`. If target P depends on target G, and I run `bazel build :P`, I want both targets to be built with `copts = ["-DMY_DEFINE"]`, along with all dependencies of target G, etc.

The [cc_binary.defines](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.defines) argument propagates in the *opposite* direction: all targets that depend on some target A will receive all of target A's `define`s.

Limitations:

- prefer to avoid custom command line flags, I don't control how people call `bazel {build,test}`
- duplicating the entire tree of dependency targets is not practical

It doesn't appear possible to set the value of a `config_setting` from within a BUILD file or a target, so it seems a `select`-based solution couldn't work.

Previous work:

- https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/rZps4nqYqt8/m/YS_pZD6oAQAJ - 2017, recommends "parallel trees" or custom macros (of which we already have many, it would be challenging to wrap them in another)
- [Propagate copts to all dependencies in Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186487/propagate-copts-to-all-dependencies-in-bazel) - I believe these all depend on custom command line flags as well

Answer (score 2):

Creating a [user-defined build setting](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#user-defined-build-settings) doesn't require command-line flags. If you set `flag = False`, then it actually can't be set on the command line. You can use a [user-defined transition](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/config.html#user-defined-transitions) to set it instead.

I think something like this will do what you're looking for (save it in `extra_copts.bzl`):

```py
def _extra_copts_impl(ctx):
    context = cc_common.create_compilation_context(
        defines = depset(ctx.build_setting_value)
    )
    return [CcInfo(compilation_context = context)]

extra_copts = rule(
    implementation = _extra_copts_impl,
    build_setting = config.string_list(flag = False),
)

def _use_extra_copts_implementation(ctx):
    return [ctx.attr._copts[CcInfo]]

use_extra_copts = rule(
    implementation = _use_extra_copts_implementation,
    attrs = "_copts": attr.label(default = "//:extra_copts")},
)

def _add_copts_impl(settings, attr):
    return {"//:extra_copts": ["MY_DEFINE"]}

_add_copts = transition(
    implementation = _add_copts_impl,
    inputs = [],
    outputs = ["//:extra_copts"],
)

def _with_extra_copts_implementation(ctx):
    infos = [d[CcInfo] for d in ctx.attr.deps]
    return [cc_common.merge_cc_infos(cc_infos = infos)]

with_extra_copts = rule(
    implementation = _with_extra_copts_implementation,
    attrs = {
        "deps": attr.label_list(cfg = _add_copts),
        "_allowlist_function_transition": attr.label(
            default = "@bazel_tools//tools/allowlists/function_transition_allowlist"
        )
    },
)
```

and then in the `BUILD` file:

```py
load("//:extra_copts.bzl", "extra_copts", "use_extra_copts", "with_extra_copts")

extra_copts(name = "extra_copts", build_setting_default = [])

use_extra_copts(name = "use_extra_copts")

cc_library(
    name = "G",
    deps = [":use_extra_copts"],
)

with_extra_copts(
    name = "P_deps",
    deps = [":G"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "P",
    deps = [":P_deps"],
)
```

`extra_copts` is the build setting. It returns a [CcInfo](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/CcInfo.html) directly, which means it's straightforward to do any other C++ library swapping with the same approach. Its default is effectively an "empty" `CcInfo` which won't do anything to libraries that depend on it.

`with_extra_copts` wraps a set of dependencies, configured to use a different `CcInfo`. This is the rule that actually changes the value, to create the second version of G with different flags.

`_add_copts` is the transition which `with_extra_copts` uses to change the value of the `extra_copts` build setting. It could examine `attr` to do something more sophisticated than adding a hard-coded list.

`use_extra_copts` pulls the `CcInfo` out of `extra_copts` so a `cc_library` can use them.

To avoid rewriting the builtin C++ rules, this uses wrapper rules to pull the copts out and do the transition. You might want to create macros to bundle the wrapper rules along with the corresponding cc_library. Alternatively, you could use [rules_cc's my_c_archive](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/examples/my_c_archive/my_c_archive.bzl) as a starting point to create custom rules that reuse the core implementation of the builtin C++ rules while integrating the transition and use of the build setting into a single rule.

Comment: _create_compilation_context_ seems to set _defines_ as it is used here, not _copts_, looking at the docs _create_compile_variables_ with _user_compile_flags_ seems the right way to go here, but then it needs some weird FeatureConfiguration and CCToolchainInfo stuff, which is undocumented. I was able to find this example https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/cc/find_cc_toolchain.bzl, but not able to bend it to my needs.

Comment: [my_c_compile](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/main/examples/my_c_compile/my_c_compile.bzl) is a better example for that. There are helper functions for the complicated inputs.

Comment: I found that before, but that seems to create an entirely new C compilation rule. I would just like to add copts to all targets with the existing rules being used. Kind of like it works with the defines in your example.

Comment: Oh right, now that I look at `CcInfo` again, there is no generic list of options being passed. I think it gets complicated to design that because option parsing is order-dependent, and you want different orderings for different things.