# Does Bazel create multiple builds for all possible defines flags?

Tags: build, config, bazel

I am bulding a c++ project using bazel. I have a foo_binary.cc whose BUILD file looks like this:

```
cc_binary (
name = "foo_binary",
srcs = ["foo_binary.cc", ],
linkopts = ["-lm"],
defines = ["__flag1__"],
deps = ["//......./foo_library",])
```

The defines flag above can take 2 values: "**flag1**" or "**flag2**". Using #ifdef, these flag values are used inside the foo_library.h file to set constants during compile time. So whenever I build the foo_binary, does it create different foo_library objects depending on the flag in cc_binary config? I observed that it doesn't. I tried changing the defines value from "flag1" to "flag2", but the foo_library objects are not modified. How does this work? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to create multiple versions of each library, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65840063/2263152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defines` flags are visible only for the `foo_binary` target and all targets, which depend on the `foo_binary` (in your case there is no such a target). Thus your defines will be not visibile in a `foo_library` source files. It is ok, because Bazel operate on the acyclic build graph, and you want to create a cycle: `foo_binary` depends on `foo_library` code, and `foo_library` depends on `foo_binary` `defines`.

Possible solutions:

- make distinct `cc_library` for each possible `defines` combination, use `defines` in a `cc_library` rule (recommended)
- make your library a header-only library, so all code will be affected by current target flags (but it can also slow your compilation times)
- set defines flag at global level using `.bazelrc` or during command line invocation (unrecommended, because it affects every target)

```
# .bazelrc

build --copt -D__flag1__
```

Comment: Thanks Slay. The foo_library was able to access the flag set in foo_binary BUILD file. I checked this by printing the constant values in foo_library.h. But according to "defines" functionality, this shouldn't happen right?

Comment: No. It will be visible in `*.h` files, but not in `*.cpp` files, if you have them in your `cc_library`. If your library is made purely from headers, then it will as you would like to. That is the `header-only library` case